# Working in Information Technology at sustainable companies

Tags: careers

Which are the companies fighting the good fight when it comes to sustainability, that have a large IT branch?

I know about Tesla Motors, and I know that many NGOs also have IT needs, but I've yet come across a proper list. Is there one available?

I'm looking forward to a more sustainable life by working in the proper industries.

Comment: The first option; I would like to be a worker/supplier for that IT branch.

Comment: I'm not sure such a list exists (I would also be interested in this list myself!) It's been my experience that most (smaller) NGOs have a rather small IT department and outsource much of their IT needs. Perhaps a good place to start is trying to find companies that make software for life-cycle analysis or traceability systems for organic or fair trade food?

Comment: I don't think such a list exists either.  But it depends what you mean by "large".  I work for an NGO that has an in-house IT team of 20 (out of 350 UK staff), and the larger NGOs are big organisations by anyone's standards.

Comment: You may find that it's not as rewarding as you suspect. I worked at a mid sized non-profit (500-1000 employees depending on whether or not you count volunteers as 'employees') focused on sustainability, and the job was pretty much like any other IT job, except a lot more focus on revenue and cost cutting since money was tight... the actual sustainability took a back seat to keeping the organization alive by bringing in revenue (donations, membership, etc). IT sustainability projects had to show that could pay for themselves financially and weren't done just because it was more sustainable.

Comment: @Johnny I agree. I've heard it makes more sense to simply stay at your current job if cushy then donate to support sustainability NGOs

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Perhaps not entirely what you are looking for, but it's the best I can think of. You can search for companies on the [B(enefit) Corporation website](http://www.bcorporation.net/). B Corp is an international label that certifies that a company

> meet[s] rigorous standards of social and environmental performance, accountability, and transparency [[source](http://www.bcorporation.net/what-are-b-corps)]

Their [search engine](http://www.bcorporation.net/community/find-a-b-corp) has a few filtering options; country, state, city and industry. One of the industry categories is 'IT Software & Services/Web Design' with currently 91 companies listed.

However, you cannot search for sizes of companies or companies with large IT departments so it may still be difficult to find those.

Comment: For someone who is in the US, I suppose this does bring quite a bit of relevant information. I think some really heavy digging is needed for a complete answer to this

Comment: I am surprised there is only one IT firm in Germany, though.

Comment: Companies have to contact B-Corp themselves to get assessed. I've only recently learned that this label exists myself so it may be that the label is not widely known in Germany yet.

Comment: If you are specifically interested in German companies; there are 2 large German companies who's names pop up sometimes in the context of sustainability;
Siemens and Henkel. You can find them in this [top 100 list](http://www.corporateknights.com/reports/global-100/2015-global-100-results/) and in this [article](http://www.ibtimes.com/germany-has-more-leading-sustainable-companies-us-uk-japan-combined-1404942) for example. But I think the top100 list is a bit questionable. BTW SAP is a multi-national IT company who take sustainability very seriously.

Answer (score 3):

1) There's a special ["sustainability" category on AngelList](https://angel.co/sustainability/jobs) if you consider jobs in startups. IT jobs can be found there as well as non-IT. What's really nice is that you can figure out a company's mission simply by looking at its short description, eg:

> The climate impact of everything made accessible to everyone.

or

> The digital sourcing platform - faster, leaner and more responsible supply chains

etc.

2) As for B Corp mentioned earlier, they even provide job listings on a [separate website](https://www.bwork.com/). IT jobs are listed there as well as non-IT, but filters make it easier to find what you need.

3) You might also consider browsing indexes of ethical and sustainable alternatives and manually checking "career" webpages of those companies which attract your attention. Such indexes are the following: [ethical](https://ethical.net/), [ethical consumer](https://www.ethicalconsumer.org/) (especially their "technology" category), [rank a brand](https://www.rankabrand.org/) ("telecom", "online", "electronics" categories, although many companies are not ranked yet).

4) UPD: I recently discovered [Climate.Careers](https://www.climate.careers/) - a specialized job discovery platform connecting climate-impactful companies with mission-driven talent. You can filter jobs:

- by impact areas (e.g. ecosystems & biodiversity, food & agriculture),
- more specific by climate solutions (e.g. afforestation, vertical farming),
- by role (ICT-related Engineering: Software, Data Analyst, Data Scientist, Design, Quality Assurance, Project Manager and so on);
- and more parameters.

There's quite a lot of job opportunities listed there, including well-known companies such as Ecosia, Too Good To Go, Leap, but not limited to.